# Opening ASUS Zenbook 15 UX533FD

Tags: asus-laptop, laptop-repair, case

Was all set to upgrade my ASUS Zenbook 15 UX533FD today with a new 2TB NVMe SSD (up from the 500GB SSD it shipped with), or so I thought.

Reviews say, and visual inspection of the notebook's chassis agrees, that one need only remove the screws visible around the sides of the bottom cover (I counted ten) and the unit should open right up. I must be missing something.

I didn't apply too much force for fear of bending/breaking trim, but the bottom cover of *my* unit at least, seems intent on staying put, even with all the screws removed.

Pulling up in numerous locations with a small suction cup yielded nothing useful, only raising the lower chassis off of the screen when pulled far enough from the hinge. There were no locations that felt safe to pry on with a spudger; the trim around the bottom cover on this model appears very thin, and liable to bend.

Other Zenbook models, like the same year's (2018) Zenbook 14, allegedly have hidden screws, but reviewers explicitly said this model does *not*.

My internal drive isn't full just yet, and I have a few weeks before the new SSD's return deadline in case I do eventually give up. Since I have some time to spare, I hope someone who's already opened this model can give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Lenovo and some other brands which make the Hardware Maintenance Manual easy to find, all I could find is your [User Manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX433FA/0409_E14245_UX333_433_533_A.pdf). It does not illustrate drive replacement.

Therefore, I suggest you [contact ASUS Support](https://icr-am.asus.com/webchat/icr.html?rootTreeId=AM.US.EN-US&treeId=AM.US.EN-US&tenantId=EN-US&_ga=2.30579004.2079693756.1564173458-1959752819.1554754024). In the left windowpane, click on **Laptops** then **Hard Drives And Storage**, and begin a chat session to ask them.

Comment: Indeed, the user manual is fairly useless. So useless (to me) that I'm not even mad they didn't include it in the box.

Comment: I contacted support, described the question, and the agent disconnected without saying anything after a roughly ten-minute wait. Perhaps I'll try again tomorrow, but based on the boilerplate he did paste in before disappearing, they seem disinclined to talk about anything related to hardware modification. Frustrating.